# MySql trigger with where clause

Tags: mysql

This is my first trigger in MySql and I am having a few problems. I tried both of these pieces of code but both would not compile.  I got it to work without the where clause.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_meal_details
AFTER INSERT ON meal_details
FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO sql_changes
 SET
 sc_table='book_room',
 sc_reason='DINNER1',
 sc_key='bh_no=NEW.bh_no,date=NEW.md_date',
 sc_value='1', 
 sc_done =0
WHERE not exists (select 1 from booking where bh_no = NEW.bh_no and bo_date = NEW.md_date and bo_meals < 1)


CREATE TRIGGER ins_meal_details AFTER INSERT meal_details FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from booking where bh_no = NEW.bh_no and bo_date = NEW.md_date and bo_meals < 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO sql_changes (sc_table, sc_reason, sc_key, sc_value, sc_done )
    VALUES ('book_room','DINNER1', 'bh_no=NEW.bh_no,date=NEW.md_date','1', 0);
END IF
END
```

Comment: `INSERT` does not use `SET`.  Remove `SET`.

Comment: "both would not compile" with what errors? perhaps those indicate the cause being that typo.

Comment: I edited the above to read 'CREATE TRIGGER ins_meal_details' which works, but without the where clause.

Comment: this works:
 CREATE TRIGGER ins_meal_details
AFTER INSERT ON meal_details
FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO sql_changes
 SET
 sc_table='book_room',
 sc_reason='DINNER1',
 sc_key='bh_no=NEW.bh_no,date=NEW.md_date',
 sc_value='1', 
 sc_done =0

Comment: Your second trigger uses begin..end so you need to set delimiters. and a terminator after the end if

Comment: this does not:
 CREATE TRIGGER ins_meal_details
AFTER INSERT ON meal_details
FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO sql_changes
 SET
 sc_table='book_room',
 sc_reason='DINNER1',
 sc_key='bh_no=NEW.bh_no,date=NEW.md_date',
 sc_value='1', 
 sc_done =0
 WHERE not exists (select 1 from booking where bh_no = NEW.bh_no and bo_date = NEW.md_date and bo_meals < 1)

Comment: @P.Salmon I tried with delimiters but the where clause was still causing problems

Comment: I was referring to the second trigger - where you are also missing  ON in the create.. Your FIRST trigger is not terminated..

Comment: I am doing this in phpMyAdmin which seems to have an implicit delimiter.  I still can not get either to work

Comment: *phpMyAdmin which seems to have an implicit delimiter* No.

Comment: @Akina You are right.  the delimiter was needed in the trigger.. thanks and thanks for the CONCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ins_meal_details
AFTER INSERT 
ON meal_details
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO sql_changes (sc_table, 
                         sc_reason,
                         sc_key,
                         sc_value, 
                         sc_done)
SELECT 'book_room',
       'DINNER1',
       CONCAT('bh_no=',NEW.bh_no,',date=',NEW.md_date),
       1, 
       0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM booking 
                  WHERE bh_no = NEW.bh_no 
                    AND bo_date = NEW.md_date 
                    AND bo_meals < 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql did not like the select/where exists in my code when there is no table specified.  This was due to using version 5.6 of MySql server.
This will not work: `select 'works' where exists (select 1 from my-table)`
The fix would be thanks to @akina to add from DUAL.  The best solution.

I got round it by using a count(*) instead :-

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_meal_details;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_meal_details
    AFTER INSERT ON meal_details FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (select count(*) from booking where bh_no = NEW.bh_no and bo_date = NEW.md_date and bo_meals < 1) > 0 THEN
INSERT INTO sql_changes (sc_table, 
                         sc_reason,
                         sc_key,
                         sc_value, 
                         sc_done)
VALUES ('book_room','DINNER1', CONCAT('bh_no=',NEW.bh_no,',date=',NEW.md_date),'New Value', 0);

        END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *This will not work: `select 'works' where exists (select 1 from my-table)`* Justify your statement (which is more than controversial). Maybe you cannot execute the query because you have used minus sign in the tablename without proper quoting?

Comment: I can only tell you what is happening with my version of mysql but this is what I get :


'Error
SQL query: Documentation


select 'works' where exists (select 1 from booking)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where exists (select 1 from booking)' at line 1'

Comment: This must work. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63eb6c6a5dcaa6eb8bfa6d3dad297620). You have some problem elsewhere. Show exact query text and exact error message, specify DBMS version precisely.

Comment: I see what the problem is now.. I am using Server version: 5.6.47 .  using your fiddle it does not work if set to a lower version.

Comment: On the version 5.6 you must add oracle-style `FROM dual`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=84948ab27caa826e9d40c5ba43f07cec).